# react state not updating properly for file uploader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, frontend, state

I am trying to make a drag and drop feature with some files. I want to make it so that when a user drags and drops multiple files, those files are all added to a list. However, only one of the files that are dragged end up being added to the list and I am not sure why. here is how I am updating the state for the list of files:

```
   files.forEach(element => {
    onFileAdded({
        file_list: [
            ...file_list,
            element
        ]
        
    })
   });
```

Files is essentially what the user drags and when I log it, it looks something like this:
[image]

In my head I would assume that each file in files would be iterated through and added to file_list.

`onFileAdded` is the method im using to update the state for `file_list`. If I drag and drop multiple files however, I notice that instead of all of the files being added to the file_list, only one of them is. I have a feeling this has something to do with how im using the spread operator but I am not 100% sure. Any insights would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you used `<input type={"file"} multiple />` element. Let's say you have empty array and you want to update it.

```
const [arr,setArr] = useState([])

const onChange = e=> {
    const {files} = e.target;
    const tempArr = [];
    for (let i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; i++) {
      tempArr.push(files[i]);
    }
    setArr(prev=> ([...prev,...tempArr]))
}

return (
  <input onChange={onChange} type={"file"} multiple />
)
```